# XGboost and XGb.DMatrix

Tags: r, rstudio, xgboost, xgbclassifier

am getting this error when using XGBoost in R

```
Error in xgb.DMatrix(data, label = label, missing = missing) : 
  'data' has class 'character' and length 1791.
  'data' accepts either a numeric matrix or a single filename.
```

Below is the code am running

```
#importing the dataset
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin <- read.csv("CompletedDataImputed_HR_Admin.csv")

#Use factor function to convert categorical data to numerical data
XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin$Salary = factor(XGBoostDataSet_Hr_Admin$Salary, levels =c('L','M', 'H', 'V'), labels =c(1,2,3,4))


#split the data in train dataset and test dataset


#fitting XGBoost to the Training Test
library(xgboost)
classifier = xgboost(data = as.matrix(training_set[-10]), label = training_set$Employee_Turnover, nrounds = 10)
```

Comment: you still have characters insider training_set[-10], thats why everything is converted to character

Comment: hello StupidWolf,
I have been able to resolve the issue, i needed to added the as.numeric when converting categorical values to numerical values

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve the issue, i needed to added the as.numeric when converting categorical values to numerical values